# Apple Match-O Linker Error when use framework

Tags: xcode, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

I add the framework VTCBay.framework to my project (this framework was writen by Objective-C and I use Swift). But when I use VTCNaviController, Xcode shows this error:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to clean the project?

Comment: try to add -ObjC in other linker flags in Build Settings